# Cannot attach source when using external folder (eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on an Eclipse project (Eclipse 3.6.2 + Android ADT + BlackBerry plug-in) where I need to share code between Android, BlackBerry, and JavaSE projects.

I moved the platform-independent code to a separate folder and created the following structure

```
CoreCode - java project
  - /src - platform independent code

CorePlusDroid - Android library project with core code plus Android-specific classes 
  - /src - Android-specific code   
  - /core_src - linked source from CoreCode/src (via Source tab in Java Build Path)

DroidApp - Android application that uses CorePlusDroid library
  - /src
  - /gen
  - /assets
  etc
```

The DroidApp builds and runs ok, but when I try to browse to classes from CoreCode or step into one of them with the debugger I get "Source not found" page.  I tried clicking the "Change Attached Source..." button and setting the location path to /CoreCode/src or specifying this folder as an external folder, but nothing helps.  The editor still cannot locate the source code for classes in CoreCode/src.

Any idea what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?  It is really great to be able to share code between platforms, but not being able to step into it when debugging is really painful.

Thanks.